# Read OBD-II Signals Matlab (in real time)

Tags: obd-ii

I would like to decode the data obd-ii directly by Matlab (read data directly from reader obd-ii and decimal display in real time.) Should I create a Matlab interface or there is a direct method (vehicle network toolbox, for example?)

(Original question from OP in French: Bonjour,j'aimerais bien décoder les données obd-ii directement par Matlab(lire les données directement du lecteur obd-ii et les afficher en décimal en temps réel).Dois-je créer une interface sur Matlab ou il existe une méthode directe(vehicle network toolbox par exemple??)

Comment: Je suis désolé pour la traduction en anglais. Alors que n'importe qui peut poser des questions, tous les messages doivent être en anglais, par les règles du site. Je crois que l'idée est de garder tout le monde sur un pied d'égalité.

Comment: @Paulster2 : You want to put the world on an equal foot? :)

Comment: There is no problem with the translation..if someone may answer me it will be nice

Comment: You may have more luck on stack overflow or programmers.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 2):

YES, there are some ways to read and show data on Matlab Simulink using vehicle network box. All the information you will find [here](http://www.mathworks.de/discovery/can-network.html). Just filter at the right ID and select the data bytes you need.